# Setting position to position of other object does not work in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I am trying out Three.js and I am trying to position a SpotLight at the position of the camera. I use the following code (stripped window creation):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    init();
});

function init() {
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
    camera.position.set(50, 10, 0);
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
    var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff );
    spotLight.position = camera.position;
    console.log(camera.position);
    console.log(spotLight.position);
}
```

I get as output that camera.position is 50,10,0 (as expected) but spotLight.position is 0,1,0 - even tough I just set it to point at the same value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
spotLight.position.set(camera.position.x, camera.position.y, camera.position.z)
```

position is read-only

Comment: But how can I make it automatically follow the camera then? Do I have to call that in my render loop?

Comment: When camera position changes seems enough... I am new to three.js so I do not know if something exists to do that automatically.

Comment: When camera position changes: `spotLight.position.copy( camera.position )`.

Answer (score 0):

Since SpotLight and Camera are objects (Object3D), you can simply add the spotlight to the camera. The light will be moved, rotated etc. with the camera without any further position copying. In this case you have to position the light relative to the camera:

```
camera.add(spotLight);
spotLight.position.set(0,0,1);
spotLight.target = camera;
```